# question about camera geometric distortion correction

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

In OpenCV implementation, instrinsic parameters of the camera is used to correct geometric distortion. 
So camera calibration is performed to obtain instrinsic parameters using multiple chessboard images.

Currently I learned that geometric distortion can be corrected using only one chessboard image.
I try to figure out how it is done, but still can't find one way to do it.

http://www.imatest.com/docs/distortion-methods-and-modules/

https://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/imaging/distortion/

I find the two above links. It describes the radial distortion. However we can't
guarantee that the camera is parallel to the chessboard when capturing the chessboard.
I can detect the corners of the chessboard, but some corners is distorted, so I can't
fit lines because fitting can only handle noise.

Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402612007735) and this [paper](http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/vgl/faisal/paper/distortion.pdf). Moreover, this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7064445) proves that you can correct distortion using single image without calibration target based on identifying straight lines on image such as edges of the buildings.
I don't know whether this functionality is implemented in OpenCV but the math in those papers is should be relatively easy to implement it using OpenCV.